# How to control movieClip from frame2 but code is frame one

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I need to access movieclip from different frame. Look here movieClip_1 is in frame 1. So it will trace and work properly but movieClip_2 is in frame 2. So it will show this error:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at mouseclik_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()
```

But I need to access movieclip_2 from frame 1 coding. I will not write code in frame 2:

```
stop();
movieClip_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler_2);

function fl_MouseClickHandler_2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("Mouse clicked");
}

movieClip_2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler_3);

function fl_MouseClickHandler_3(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    trace("Mouse clicked");
}
```

Comment: Why is it on Frame 2? Can your code not just add to stage using `addChild` when you need to show it? Or else put it on frame 1 (new layer) anyway but have code to say `movieClip_2.visible = false` (exists but is not visible or clickable) then when you need to show instead of `gotoAndStop(2)` you just say `movieClip_2.visible = true` (now visible & responds to clicks).

Comment: thats good way to use addChild  . thanks for your suggestion . no more confusion

Comment: Alternatively: why can't you just put the code on frame 2?

Comment: See **[an example of the setup here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35935180/2057709)**...