# Program help needed in Actionscript 3 game

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, adobe

I have been making this game in AS3 and the basics work. The thing i am having trouble with is making a 'start' menu appear when the game starts but also when the player dies. I have been trying the .visible code but that didn't seem to work.

Question: What code do i add to my game that makes the start button appear when the game starts but also when the player dies. Code:

```
package{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.events.Event; //used for ENTER_FRAME event

public class Main extends MovieClip{

    //constants
    const gravity:Number = 1.5;            //gravity of the game
    const dist_btw_obstacles:Number = 300; //distance between two obstacles
    const ob_speed:Number = 8;             //speed of the obstacle
    const jump_force:Number = 15;          //force with which it jumps

    //variables
    var player:Player = new Player();      
    var lastob:Obstacle = new Obstacle();  //varible to store the last obstacle in the obstacle array
    var obstacles:Array = new Array();     //an array to store all the obstacles
    var yspeed:Number = 0;                 //A variable representing the vertical speed of the bird
    var score:Number = 0;                  //A variable representing the score

    public function Main(){
        init();
    }

    function init():void {
        //initialize all the variables
        player = new Player();
        lastob = new Obstacle();
        obstacles = new Array();
        yspeed = 0;
        score = 0;

        //add player to center of the stage the stage
        player.x = stage.stageWidth/2;
        player.y = stage.stageHeight/2;
        addChild(player);

        //create 3 obstacles ()
        createObstacle();
        createObstacle();
        createObstacle();

        //Add EnterFrame EventListeners (which is called every frame) and KeyBoard EventListeners
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,onEnterFrameHandler);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, key_up);
    }

    private function key_up(event:KeyboardEvent){
        if(event.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE){
            //If space is pressed then make the bird
            yspeed = -jump_force;
        }
    }

    function restart(){
        if(contains(player))
            removeChild(player);
            for(var i:int = 0; i < obstacles.length; ++i){
                if(contains(obstacles[i]) && obstacles[i] != null)
                removeChild(obstacles[i]);
                obstacles[i] = null;
            }
            obstacles.slice(0);
            init();
    }

    function onEnterFrameHandler(event:Event){
        //update player
        yspeed += gravity;
        player.y += yspeed;

        //restart if the player touches the ground
        if(player.y + player.height/2 > stage.stageHeight){
            restart();
        }

        //Don't allow the bird to go above the screen
        if(player.y - player.height/2 < 0){
            player.y = player.height/2;
        }

        //update obstacles
        for(var i:int = 0;i<obstacles.length;++i){
            updateObstacle(i);
        }

        //display the score
        scoretxt.text = String(score);
    }

    //This functions update the obstacle
    function updateObstacle(i:int){
        var ob:Obstacle = obstacles[i];

        if(ob == null)
        return;
        ob.x -= ob_speed;

        if(ob.x < -ob.width){
            //if an obstacle reaches left of the stage then change its position to the back of the last obstacle
            changeObstacle(ob);
        }

        //If the bird hits an obstacle then restart the game
        if(ob.hitTestPoint(player.x + player.width/2,player.y + player.height/2,true)
           || ob.hitTestPoint(player.x + player.width/2,player.y - player.height/2,true)
           || ob.hitTestPoint(player.x - player.width/2,player.y + player.height/2,true)
           || ob.hitTestPoint(player.x - player.width/2,player.y - player.height/2,true)){
            restart();
        }

        //If the bird got through the obstacle without hitting it then increase the score
        if((player.x - player.width/2 > ob.x + ob.width/2) && !ob.covered){
            ++score;
            ob.covered = true;
        }
    }

    //This function changes the position of the obstacle such that it will be the last obstacle and it also randomizes its y position
    function changeObstacle(ob:Obstacle){
        ob.x = lastob.x + dist_btw_obstacles;
        ob.y = 100+Math.random()*(stage.stageHeight-200);
        lastob = ob;
        ob.covered = false;
    }

    //this function creates an obstacle
    function createObstacle(){
        var ob:Obstacle = new Obstacle();
        if(lastob.x == 0)
        ob.x = 800;
        else
        ob.x = lastob.x + dist_btw_obstacles;
        ob.y = 100+Math.random()*(stage.stageHeight-200);
        addChild(ob);
        obstacles.push(ob);
        lastob = ob;
    }


}
```

}

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is the start button visibility code in your question?

Comment: This smells suspiciously of a homework assignment?

Comment: There's nothing about a menu in your code.

Answer (score 0):

- Draw a Box (with colour fill but no outline). Convert to `MovieClip` type. Give a name eg: "Menu"
- It will be
  a container for your menu. Add content by double-clicking it, to add
  graphics & text on new layers. Or if you have already have content on some other frames, then just **"cut frames"** and later do a **"paste frames"** inside the timeline of this new movieClip.
- When you converted, it was added to the **Library** section
  (`ctrl + L`). Find it ("Menu") in the library and right-click then choose "properties". In
  **linkage** section click "export for actionscript". The **Class name** should become "Menu" automatically. Now just click "OK".

Example usage in game code.. (ie: To add to screen or remove etc)

```
//# load the movieClip...
var Menu_Screen : Menu = new Menu(); //# Menu is linkage name given in Library

//# Adding to screen...
gameContainer_MC.addChild( Menu_Screen );
gameCcontainer_MC.removeChild( Menu_Screen );

//# Controlling the movieClip...
Menu_Screen.x = 50;
gameContainer_MC.Menu_Screen.x = 50;
```